# How to display Flash-based webpages in a QT Application?

Tags: c++, flash, qt

Im trying to show a flash animation in my QT application, I'm doing it by a QWebView. This is my code:

```
webpage = new QWebPage(this->window);

webpage->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
webpage->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);

webview->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,480,800));

webview->move(QPoint(0,0));

webview->load(QUrl(flash->file));

webview->show();
```

So, Im able to show regular pages, but the pages that got a Flash animation doesnt appears. I receive a blank page and a symbol from adobe, like "Get flashplayer".
I already have it, those pages load ok in Firefox and Chrome. I have put the NPSWF32.dll e my project folder and in others standar paths, but it Didnt work. So I do not really know what to do now. Hope you guys can helpme, I couldnt find the plugin file in Firefox or Chrome folders, so I downloaded another NPSWF32 to put in the project folder, maybe is that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

look here where Qt expects to find plugin:
http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support

Your plugin (NPSWF32) seems to be right

Comment: I've already did it. Didn't work. I Put the NPSWF32.dll on %USERDATA%\Mozilla\plugins
Is there other place I can place it?